GeoServer : Workspace for WMTS
I'd like clarification on the organization of WMTS with GeoServer and GWC integrated.
Currently, workspaces are used to partition webservices by theme and for security reasons.
https://geoserver-tst.be/geoserver/buildings/wms
https://geoserver-tst.be/geoserver/cemetery/wms
When I want to use WMTS, gwc provides a general link to all the services.
https://geoserver-tst.be/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts
capabilities returns the bxlgis and cemetery workspace layers.
Is it possible to have a separate WMTS endpoint for these two workspaces?
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Use the following endpoint url structure
https://geoserver-tst.be/geoserver/WORKSPACE/gwc/service/wmts?service=WMTS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities
